# Scala generic invocation on overloaded methods

Tags: scala, generics

I am new to Scala - and while generating Excel files with Apache POI, I tried removing duplication in my code via this generic:

```
def addCell[A](
  row:       org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row,
  idxColumn: Int,
  data:      A)
  :
  Unit = 
{
  row.createCell(idxColumn).setCellValue(data)
}
```

Unfortunately, the compiler reported:

```
[error] .../mycode.scala:32: overloaded method value setCellValue \
with alternatives:
[error]   (x$1: Boolean)Unit <and>
[error]   (x$1: String)Unit <and>
[error]   (x$1: org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.RichTextString)Unit <and>
[error]   (x$1: java.util.Calendar)Unit <and>
[error]   (x$1: java.util.Date)Unit <and>
[error]   (x$1: Double)Unit
[error]  cannot be applied to (A)
[error]     row.createCell(idxColumn).setCellValue(data)
[error]                               ^
[error] one error found
[error] (compile:compile) Compilation failed
```

I don't get it - whoever calls `addCell` will be passing a specific type `A` (the type of the 3rd argument, `data`) so the generic form should be able to dispatch to the proper overloaded form of `setCellValue`.

I am probably missing something obvious - any help most appreciated.

**EDIT**: To make it clear - my code is currently doing this:

```
field match {
  case i:Int => row.createCell(idxCol).setCellValue(i)
  case l:Long => row.createCell(idxCol).setCellValue(l)
  case f:Float => row.createCell(idxCol).setCellValue(f)
  case d:Double => row.createCell(idxCol).setCellValue(d)
  case s:String => row.createCell(idxCol).setCellValue(s)
      ...
```

And I'd like to avoid the obvious repetition via a generic call to something like

```
field match {
  case i:Int => setCell(row, idxCol, i)
  case l:Long => setCell(row, idxCol, l)
  case f:Float => setCell(row, idxCol, f)
  ...
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Most statically typed languages do not support dynamic method selection based on parameter types. You should use `scala.Dynamic` (http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Dynamic) in case you need similar feature. (Or you can use pattern matching to select the appropriate overload runtime.)

Comment: This could also be a good use case for typeclasses.

Comment: The call has to compile to a specific method invocation - generics don't exist at runtime. The safe, idiomatic way is @v6ak's second suggestion, using typeclasses. For a less safe/generic approach you could write a non-generic method accepting `data: Any` and then doing a `match`/`case` for the different types, i.e. `data match { case b: Boolean => setCellValue(b); case s: String => setCellValue(s); ... }`

Comment: @Ryan: Can you elaborate? A gist showcasing how one would apply typeclasses to this problem would be very helpful.

Comment: @lmm: Generics definitely don't exist at runtime - but my point is that the compiler can see (at compile-time) that when I e.g. call `addCell(someRow, 5, "asdfas")` the type of A is fixed - a string - so it can instantiate a form of the generic (for that specific call) that dispatches to the String version of `setCellValue`. This would be a compile-time operation (and I think a C++ compiler would do this). Doing a match/case is what I am in fact doing right now - I was just hoping to remove the repetition with a generic.

Comment: @ttsiodras v6ak provided a typeclass answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most straightforward way is writing a separate method for each type:

```
def addCell(
  row:       org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row,
  idxColumn: Int,
  data:      Boolean)
  :
  Unit = 
{
  row.createCell(idxColumn).setCellValue(data)
}

def addCell(
  row:       org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row,
  idxColumn: Int,
  data:      String)
  :
  Unit = 
{
  row.createCell(idxColumn).setCellValue(data)
}
```

This is OK if you need just addCell to write this way.

---

If you need some code for more methods, you may consider a more advanced approach that limits the boilerplate per method.

A sketch of the more advanced approach:

1. Define a cellSetter trait, which can set a value of given type to the cell.

   ```
   trait CellSetter[A]{
       def setCell(cell: Cell, data: A): Unit
   }
   ```
2. Implement CellSetters for all the relevant types, e.g.:

   ```
   implicit val stringCellSetter = new CellSetter[String](){
     def setCell(cell: Cell, data: String){
       cell.setCellValue(data)
     }
   }
   ```
3. Make some sugar:

   ```
   implicit class RichCell(cell: Cell){
       def setCellValue[A](data: A)(implicit cellSetter: CellSetter[A]) = cellSetter.setCell(cell, data)
   }
   ```
4. Create some nice generic code for addCell:

   ```
   def addCell[A: CellSetter](
     row:       org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row,
     idxColumn: Int,
     data:      A)
     :
     Unit = 
   {
     row.createCell(idxColumn).setCellValue(data)
   }
   ```

Comment: I appreciate the effort involved in your response, but my whole point was to remove repetition. I currently use a match/case that delegates to `setCellValue` in each different case - that is, `case i:Int => ....setCellValue(i) case f:Float => ...setCellValue(f) ... ` etc - and was hoping to follow the DRY principle using a generic form - moving the repetition from my match/case to an even larger set of helpers is not what I had in mind.

Comment: It will be always a tradeoff. You can try using reflection to do it in the most DRY way without changing the library. You can do the pattern matching. Neither of these approaches is type-safe. You could write some fallback (e.g. using .toString() for unknown types), but is allows accidental passing of a value of a strange type, like Array[_]. Moreover, someone may find the API strange like a Rails API.

Comment: On the other hand, if you use either the overloading or using the CellSetter approach, this is rather type-safe. The overloading is good as one-time non-extensible solution. The CellSetter is good if you either want to use it in more than one method (i.e. not just in addCell method) or if you want user allow to write an extension.

Comment: I just read a tutorial about typeclasses, to understand what you did. I believe you are missing an `implicit` in the `RichCell.setCellValue`'s `cellSetter` parameter. Also, In the `String` version of `setCell`, you probably meant `cell.setCellValue(data)`, not `cell.setCell(data)`. Right?

Comment: Both are right, fixed. (Note that some types like Cell may be wrongly named, I just guessed the type names.)

Comment: Also: the latest compiler (currently 2.11.4) crashes with your `implicit val ... = new CellSetter...`. I opened a [bug report](https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-9041) with a standalone version of the code, and it is confirmed. My way around it was using `implicit object ... extends CellSetter`, which works fine.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I ever do anything like this, but I was curious whether specialization helps.

Minimally, you'd like to avoid boxing the primitives.

It turns out that specialization doesn't help much, because specialized methods don't dispatch to unspecialized ones. I think I've read about this problem before.

In the following, specializing `add` works OK. One version uses a `ClassTag` to select a reference type, or the other one handles primitives. But the commented-out code just calls `setCellValue(Any)`; it's not true that the boolean version calls `setCellValue(Boolean)`.

The version commented-in seems to crash the back-end...

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag
import java.util.Date

trait Setter {
  def setCellValue(b: Boolean) = println("bool")
  def setCellValue(s: String) = println("str")
  def setCellValue(n: Double) = println("double")
  def setCellValue(d: Date) = println("date")
}

object Test extends App {
  def add[@specialized(Boolean, Double) A <: AnyVal](s: Setter, a: A) = {
    /*
    class ASetter extends Setter {
      override def setCellValue(b: Boolean) = s setCellValue b
      override def setCellValue(n: Double) = s setCellValue n
      def setCellValue(x: Any) = ???
    }
    (new ASetter) setCellValue a
    */
    a match {
      case b: Boolean => s setCellValue b
      case d: Double  => s setCellValue d
      case _ => ???
    }
  }
  def add[A: ClassTag](s: Setter, a: A) = a match {
    //case _: Boolean | _: Double => s setCellValue a
    case d: Date   => s setCellValue d
    case x: String => s setCellValue x
    case _ => ???
  }

  val s = new Setter {}
  add(s, new Date)
  add(s, true)
}
```